# WPF Binding error on creating an element in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeviewitem

Upon dynamically making a `TreeViewItem` in code, I get binding errors relating to content alignment, even though the associated style specifies this.

```
TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem() 
{
    Header = "aString", 
    Style = wpfElement.FindResource("tviRoot") as Style 
};
```

The error I get is

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

(and a similar one for the vertical alignment)

I don't really understand why I get this error and I can't figure it out (I'm not that well-versed in WPF). The weird thing is that everything seems to work as expected, but is still massively slowed down by these errors. Can somebody help?

Edit: I had given the style property a stub name, as I didn't think it mattered, I've renamed it and included its definition below: `tviRoot`, based on `tviBaseStyle`

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="tviBaseStyle">

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--The top row contains the item's content.-->
                        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource rowHeight}" />
                        <!--The bottom row contains the item's children.-->
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- This Border and ContentPresenter displays the content of the TreeViewItem. -->
                    <Border Name="Bd" Margin="0" Padding="0"
                            Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2"
                            TextElement.FontSize="{StaticResource fontSize}"
                            TextElement.FontFamily="{StaticResource fontFamily}">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <!-- The ItemsPresenter displays the item's children. -->
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- Make each TreeViewItem show its children in a horizontal StackPanel. -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="tviRoot" TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource tviBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--The top row contains the item's content.-->
                        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource rowHeight}" />
                        <!--The bottom row contains the item's children.-->
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- This Border and ContentPresenter displays the content of the TreeViewItem. -->
                    <Border Name="Bd" Margin="0" Padding="0"
                            Background="{StaticResource rootGradient}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2"
                            TextElement.FontSize="{StaticResource fontSize}"
                            TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"
                            TextElement.FontFamily="{StaticResource fontFamily}">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- The ItemsPresenter displays the item's children. -->
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Border.Background" Value="{StaticResource rootGradientSelected}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- Make each TreeViewItem show its children in a horizontal StackPanel. -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you post code for `myStyle` where you are using binding?

Comment: For me, this style works fine. Where are you trying to add items to the tree? It may be that the tree does not completely load properly?

Comment: Yes, the style works fine. The problem arises when I programmatically try to create a new TreeViewItem (on its own, not connected to anything yet).
The weird thing is that even changing the creation code to the following doesn't get rid of the error:

`TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "aString", Style = wpfTreeView.FindResource("tviRoot") as Style, HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };`

Comment: And after the created item is added to my tree, it all looks fine and behaves as expected. So nothing really seems to go wrong, except that these errors slow down the program hugely.

Comment: See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a189f2a-91f3-4e21-a19f-52b8ef328c54/cannot-retrieve-value-using-the-binding-and-no-valid-fallback-value-exists-using-default-instead), maybe help.

Comment: It couldn't find anything of use there, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, changing the order of the creation arguments got rid of the error. (I guess it set the `TreeViewItem`'s `Header` attribute before associating a `Style`, and that's what was causing the problem..?)
I got a lot more of these errors in my application, so I can't see yet if some new ones didn't pop up somewhere else.